# Why it is not recommended to modify the object in one pipeline

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a general question about RxJava. I have seen in many places saying that It is totally not recommended to modify the object in one pipeline step. You should create a new one and pass it down, or use `doOnNext()` for side-effects.

For example

```
 Observable.fromIterable(users)
        .map(user -> {
            user.name =//do something with name);
            user.age = // do something with age);
            return user;
        }).subscribe(user -> {

        });
```

As you can see, the user object is being modified in the pipeline step. But this code works fine with no issues. But still why it is considered as a bad practice? Can anyone give a better explanation on why exactly objects should be immutable throughout the stream?

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no guarentee that the source of those objects doesn't reuse them. For example if you used the `publish` operator all inner observables would receive the same object. The original source might also try to re-use objects and thus be mutated while it shouldn't.

To reduce the chances of this happening it is recommended to create new objects when transforming within a pipeline.